# RTK: Cannot refetch a query that has not been started yet

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am getting a lot of errors in my airbrake in many places of my app, saying: `Cannot refetch a query that has not been started yet.`

I was looking around and haven't found a way to reproduce.
I assume that the error is caused either by the RTK `refetch()` or by `pollingInterval` given to the query.

I don't know if anyone has the same problem or if this is a known issue.

Since I don't really know what is causing the problem, and as the errors only started to appear lately, I thought maybe this is caused by RTK or something.

I also thought maybe it's caused by some `useEffects` like this one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user?.team !== userTeamRef.current) {
        refetch();
        userTeamRef.current = user?.team === undefined ? null : user.team;
    }
}, [user?.team, refetch]);
```

**UPDATE:**

So I was able to reproduce the error:

```
    const [joinTeam ] = useJoinTeamMutation();
    const { refetch } = useGetTeam(slugName);

    const onClick = () => {
        leaveTeam().then((res: any) => {
            if (!res.error) {
                refetch();
            }
        });
    };
```

When calling the refetch using a promise it throws the error.

Comment: RTKQuery is declarative so you should never have to refetch in an effect, only in an event handler/callback. Can you show more of the component code, where the query is?

Comment: I am only using the refetch function from the query in this case. something like:
`const { refetch } = useGetTeam(slug, {skip: !slug});`

Comment: Show more of the code - you don't need to manually refetch it if `skip` ends up being false, it'll just get refetched automatically. You might be in state-management spaghetti and need to unwind it a bit. Not a great sign that you're using a ref, but it's not entirely clear what's going on without seeing more code.

Comment: I managed to reproduce the issue, please check the update, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Refetch can be done only on already fetched data, it won't work if it is not initialized. So you might want to try the following:

```js
const { refetch, isUninitialized } = useGetTeam(slugName);
    
const refetchTeam = useCallback(() => {
  if (!isUninitialized) {
    refetch();
  }
}, [isUninitialized, refetch]);
    
const onClick = () => {
  leaveTeam().then((res: any) => {
    if (!res.error) {
      refetchTeam();
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Ohh, I never knew there was such a thing, thanks man!